# Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel-1, sentinel

I am trying to calculate NDVI using Sentinel 1, but when I tried to make a chart of it, this error is coming. Error, "Error generating chart: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string". How to figure this out?
Code Link.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/3e1ccbeab86356b6b0130877752b8aee

```
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/sawieproject/assets/Cotton_Farm");
Map.centerObject(roi);
// Convert linear backscatter to dB scale
function toDb(linear) {
  return linear.addBands(
    ee.Image().expression('10 * log10(linear)', {
      linear: linear.select(['VV', 'VH'])
    }),
    null,
    true // Replace the bands to keep image properties
  );
}

function calc_s1_ndvi(sigmaVV, sigmaVH) {
  // Convert sigma0 to Decibels
  var vh_Db = sigmaVH.log10().multiply(10.0);
  var vv_Db = sigmaVV.log10().multiply(10.0);

  // Calculate NRPB (Filgueiras et al. (2019), eq. 4)
  var NRPB = vh_Db.subtract(vv_Db).divide(vh_Db.add(vv_Db));

  // Calculate NDVI_nc with approach A3 (Filgueiras et al. (2019), eq. 14)
  var NDVInc = ee.Image(2.572).subtract(vh_Db.multiply(0.05047)).add(vv_Db.multiply(0.176)).add(NRPB.multiply(3.422));

  return NDVInc;
}

// Load Sentinel-1 data for the ROI and date range
var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .select(['VV', 'VH'])
  .filterDate('2023-04-15', '2023-07-17')
  .map(toDb);

// Calculate NDVI_nc for the filtered Sentinel-1 images
var ndviImages = sentinel1.map(function(image) {
  var sigmaVV = image.select('VV');
  var sigmaVH = image.select('VH');
  var ndvi = calc_s1_ndvi(sigmaVV, sigmaVH);

  // Convert date to Unix timestamp format
  var date = image.date().millis();

  return ndvi.rename('NDVI').set('system:time_start', date);
});

// Create a chart for mean NDVI values over time
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: ndviImages,
  regions: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  band: 'NDVI',
  xProperty: 'system:time_start', // Use the numeric format for the x-axis data
  scale: 10,
});

// ...

// Customize the chart
chart = chart.setOptions({
  title: 'Mean NDVI Over Time',
  hAxis: { title: 'Date', format: 'YYYY-MM-dd' }, // Format the date on the x-axis
  vAxis: { title: 'Mean NDVI' },
});

// Print the chart to the console
print(chart);
```

Comment: Please share your asset: `projects/sawieproject/assets/Cotton_Farm`

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/sawieproject/assets/Cotton_Farm